# After updating theme & plugin I am getting an error message

Tags: plugins, warnings

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73/sess_fst434k28vgl24a35pujpu9u43,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /home/fordhoow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-sidebars/inc/external/wpmu-lib/inc/class-thelib.php
>   on line 145
>
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path:
>   /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73) in
>   /home/fordhoow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-sidebars/inc/external/wpmu-lib/inc/class-thelib.php
>   on line 145
>
> Notice: add_submenu_page was called incorrectly. The seventh parameter
>   passed to add_submenu_page() should be an integer representing menu
>   position. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
>   (This message was added in version 5.3.0.) in
>   /home/fordhoow/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4986

Comment: Please check do you have proper file permission given to the wp include and wp admin

Comment: for folders its 755 & within folder files 644